# How to write an SQL script that needs to be executed on many databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got this:

```
SET @databasename = (SELECT DATABASE());

USE @databasename;

...SQL Querys...
```

But this don`t works for me :(

Comment: The value that SELECT DATABASE() returns will already be the default database for the query, so making it the default again with USE wouldn't do anything... And USE doesn't work with variables, you have to state the database name directly.

Comment: So i can delete the USE line and it will work with different databases?

Comment: Yes, as long as you select the database that the query should run on before executing it, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATABASE() INTO databasename;
```